# Iterating over JavaScript array in object to display in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a JS object like this:

```
{
   promo_name: "value",
   discount_type: "value",
   discount: "value",
   products: [
      { id: 1, name: 'name'},
      { id: 2, name: 'name'},  
   ]
}
```

My objective is to display the results in a view. My problem is that I do not know how to iterate over an array inside an object.

The data is coming from an Ajax request and then parsed into a JS object.

I am using jQuery `$.each` to iterate over the `res` object and display property values like this:

```
$.each(res, function (key, value) {

    $("#coupon_data").show();
    $("#coupon_details").html(
        '<div class="alert alert-success">' +
            '<h4>Promotion Details</h4>' +
            '<hr>' +
            '<p>Promotion: '     + res.promo_name    + '</p>' +
            '<p>Discount type: ' + res.discount_type + '</p>' +
            '<p>Amount: '        + res.discount      + '%</p>' +
        '</div>'
    );

});
```

The three properties (res.promo_name, res.discount_type, res.discount) display, but because the array length varies I cannot display its values like this:

`res.products[0].name`
`res.products[1].name`

I believe that I need to loop over the array that's inside the object and display the number of elements it might contain. This is where I am stuck.

Comment: `$.each(res.products, function(index, val) { ....... }`

Comment: if you just need a count, no need to loop: `res.products.length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get the count, use the attribute `length` from `Array`

```
var count = res.products ? res.products.length : 0;
```

*Something like this:*

```js
var res = {
  promo_name: "value",
  discount_type: "value",
  discount: "value",
  products: [{id: 1,name: 'name'},
             {id: 2,name: 'name'}]
};

$.each(res, function(key, value) {

  $("#coupon_data").show();
  $("#coupon_details").html(
    '<div class="alert alert-success">' +
    '<h4>Promotion Details</h4>' +
    '<hr>' +
    '<p>Promotion: ' + res.promo_name + '</p>' +
    '<p>Discount type: ' + res.discount_type + '</p>' +
    '<p>Amount: ' + res.discount + '%</p>' +
    '<p>Products: ' + (res.products ? res.products.length : 0) + '</p>' +
    '</div>'
  );

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='coupon_details'></div>
```

*If you need to show the count + product details:*

```js
var res = {
  promo_name: "value",
  discount_type: "value",
  discount: "value",
  products: [{id: 1,name: 'name1'},
             {id: 2,name: 'name2'}]
};

$.each(res, function(key, value) {

  $("#coupon_data").show();
   var html = '<div class="alert alert-success">' +
    '<h4>Promotion Details</h4>' +
    '<hr>' +
    '<p>Promotion: ' + res.promo_name + '</p>' +
    '<p>Discount type: ' + res.discount_type + '</p>' +
    '<p>Amount: ' + res.discount + '%</p>' +
    '<p>Products: ' + (res.products ? res.products.length : 0) + '</p><p>Details:</p>';
    
    if (res.products) {
      for (var i = 0, {length} = res.products; i < length; i++) {
        html += '<p><b>Name:</b>' + res.products[i].name + '</p>';
      }
    }
    
  $("#coupon_details").html(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='coupon_details'></div>
```

Comment: wouldn't [].map() make more sense to _transform_ the data?

Comment: Thank you very much Ele. Great work! Yes, I wanted to display the products as a list. Your code looks great. I especially like how you created an html variable. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Outside of a regular for loop, you can also use [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
var products = [
  { id: 123, name: 'name1',
  { id: 456, name: 'name2'
]

products.forEach(function(product) {
  // do something with each product...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some typos with your object.

```
{
   promo_name: "value",
   discount_type: "value",
   discount: "value",
   products: [
      { id: 1, name: 'name'},
      { id: 2, name: 'name'},  
   ]
}
```

Example on how to get the length of the array within the object:

```
var myObj = {
   promo_name: "value",
   discount_type: "value",
   discount: "value",
   products: [
      { id: 1, name: 'name'},
      { id: 2, name: 'name'},  
   ]
};

//length of products
myObj.products.length;

//one product
myObj.products[0];

//id of one product:
myObj.products[0].id;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can get this to be a little more performant by using a JS-equivalent of a StringBuilder, which is an array, like:

```
var h = [
    '<div class="alert alert-success">',
    '<h4>Promotion Details</h4>',
    ...
];
$("#coupon_details").html(h.join(''));
```

Second, rather than call $.each() where you have, you need to just call $.each on the property, which is an array, like:

```
$.each(res.products, function(i, product) {
    h.push('<div class=product>', product.name, '</div>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to iterate through `res` object, because there is nothing to iterate and it's not iterable, instead you should iterate your `res.products` array

```
 $("#coupon_data").show();
 $("#coupon_details").html(
   '<div class="alert alert-success">' +
   '<h4>Promotion Details</h4>' +
   '<hr>' +
   '<p>Promotion: '     + res.promo_name    + '</p>' +
   '<p>Discount type: ' + res.discount_type + '</p>' +
   '<p>Amount: '        + res.discount      + '%</p>'   
   );

 $.each(res.products, function (key, value) {
  $("#coupon_details").append('<p>Product name: '  + value.name + '</p>');
 });
 $("#coupon_details").append('</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your starting point, I'd [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the array into a string representation of all the elements.

I'm also using ES6 an arrow function and template syntax to make things a little more concise. Also, as others have noted, you don't need `$.each` to iterate an object, so I've removed that.

```js
const res = {
   promo_name: "value",
   discount_type: "value",
   discount: "value",
   products: [
      { id: 1, name: 'name'},
      { id: 2, name: 'name'},  
   ]
}

$("#coupon_data").show();
$("#coupon_details").html(
    '<div class="alert alert-success">' +
        '<h4>Promotion Details</h4>' +
        '<hr>' +
        '<p>Promotion: '     + res.promo_name    + '</p>' +
        '<p>Discount type: ' + res.discount_type + '</p>' +
        '<p>Amount: '        + res.discount      + '%</p>' +
        '<p>Products: <ul>' +
          res.products.reduce((accum,curVal) => `${accum}<li>${curVal.id}: ${curVal.name}</li>`,'') +
        '</ul></p>' +
    '</div>'
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="coupon_data">
  <div id="coupon_details">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below:

```
$.each(res, function (key, value) {

     $("#coupon_data").show();

     var productElements = '' // to store product elements

     // iterate product elements, you can use for loop also   
     res.products.map((product) => {
       var {id, name} = product;
       productElements += `<p> *any thing you want to use(${id} or ${name})* </p>\n` // html element for product items as string
     })

    $("#coupon_details").html(
     '<div class="alert alert-success">' +
        '<h4>Promotion Details</h4>' +
        '<hr>' +
        '<p>Promotion: '     + res.promo_name    + '</p>' +
        '<p>Discount type: ' + res.discount_type + '</p>' +
        '<p>Amount: '        + res.discount      + '%</p>' +
        `${productElements}` //final product items
     '</div>'
   );

});
```